# Creating an XML file in python nodes are missing

Tags: python, xml, pandas, elementtree

I want to create a XML file with elementtree library.

the XML file should look like:

```
<files>
    <file>
        <ans>EP16</ans>
        <ep></ep>
        <date>2017-03-15</date>
        <concepts>~what</concepts>
    </file>
    <file>
        <ans>EP17</ans>
        <ep>ep6665</ep>
        <date>2017-03-15</date>
        <concepts>~whatever</concepts>
     </file>
     etc
</files>
```

I try to do it in the following way:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
XMLfiles = ET.Element("files")
file= ET.SubElement(XMLfiles, "file")


nrofrows=dffiles.shape[0]
for i in range(nrofrows):
    serie=dffiles.iloc[i]
    child1=ET.SubElement(file, "an")
    child1.text=serie[0]
    child2=ET.SubElement(file, "ep")
    child2.text=serie[1]
    child3=ET.SubElement(file, "date")
    child3.text=serie[2]
    child4=ET.SubElement(file, "concepts")
    child4.text=serie[3]
```

saving the file:

```
tree2 = ET.ElementTree(XMLfiles)
filetosave=os.path.join('00DATA_output','bb.xml')
tree2.write(filetosave)
```

an XML file is created but it skips closing  for every file. the xml file created started as:

```
<files>
    <file>
        <ans>EP16</ans>
        <ep></ep>
        <date>2017-03-15</date>
        <concepts>~what</concepts>
   ... ***** closing and open <file> is missing
        <ans>EP17</ans>
        <ep>ep6665</ep>
        <date>2017-03-15</date>
        <concepts>~whatever</concepts>
    </file>
</files>
```

what is lacking in the code to open and close the file every time?
Note: Assume that the df being parsed is ok, the serie is a row of df.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want a `<file>` tag per each row in the `dffiles` thing, move that inside the loop too.

```
nrofrows = dffiles.shape[0]
for i in range(nrofrows):
    file = ET.SubElement(XMLfiles, "file")
    serie = dffiles.iloc[i]
    child1 = ET.SubElement(file, "an")
    child1.text = serie[0]
    child2 = ET.SubElement(file, "ep")
    child2.text = serie[1]
    child3 = ET.SubElement(file, "date")
    child3.text = serie[2]
    child4 = ET.SubElement(file, "concepts")
    child4.text = serie[3]
```